# Split CSV by column value, and keep header

Tags: csv, awk

This has been asked many times before but I simply can't implement the solutions properly. I have a large csv named 2017-01.csv, with a date column (it's the second column in the file) and I am splitting the file by date. The original file looks like:

```
 date
 2017-01-01
 2017-01-01
 2017-01-01
 2017-01-02
 2017-01-02
 2017-01-02
```

After the split, 2017-01-01.csv looks like

```
2017-01-01
2017-01-01
2017-01-01
```

and 2017-01-02.csv looks like

```
2017-01-02
2017-01-02
2017-01-02
```

The code I am using is

```
awk -F ',' '{print > (""$2".csv")}' 2017.csv
```

Everything works fine but I need to keep the header row. So I tried

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==1; NR > 1{print > (""$2".csv")}' 2017-01.csv
```

But I still get the same results without the header row. What am I doing wrong? I read answers to many similar questions on Stackoverflow but I just can't understand what they are doing.

I want this:

2017-01-01.csv should look like

```
date
2017-01-01
2017-01-01
2017-01-01
```

2017-01-02.csv should look like

```
date
2017-01-02
2017-01-02
2017-01-02
```

Comment: Your input and output file names are looking same? is it a typo or correct thing, please confirm?

Comment: I have edited it again to make it clear. The input and output files are different. Let me know if it makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: The `""` in your script is doing nothing, you could just remove it. [edit] your question to provide sample input/output that more truly represents your real multi-columnar data so we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
FNR==1{hdr=$2}
 FNR > 1{
   if (! hdrPrinted[$2]){
      print hdr > (""$2".csv")
      hdrPrinted[$2]=$2
  }
  print $1, $2, $3> (""$2".csv")
}' 2017-01.csv
```

And as a 1-liner

```
awk -F, ' FNR==1{hdr=$2} FNR > 1{ if (! hdrPrinted[$2]){ print hdr > (""$2".csv"); hdrPrinted[$2]=$2; } print $1, $2, $3> (""$2".csv") }' 2017-01.csv
```

Produces output

```
cat 2017\-01\-01.csv
date
  2017-01-01
  2017-01-01
  2017-01-01

cat 2017\-01\-02.csv
date
  2017-01-02
  2017-01-02
  2017-01-02
```

Note that `FNR` means FileNumber(of)Record, so each time a new file is opened, the FNR will reset to 1. This may cause problems for specific cases of processing, but generally, I think it is the better approach, allowing you to list multiple files on the cmd line, and process them all in one process.

## -----------------

Per reasonable comments below, here is more bullet-proof version which should deal with the case if more than 20 files are listed on the cmd line.

I don't have an easy way to test this, so feedback is welcome.

**AND per comments below, it still needs some work, which I don't have time for right now. Look for update Saturday afternoon.**

```
awk -F, ' FNR==1{hdr=$2}  FNR > 1{
      # length() assumes newish gawk version
      if ( length(openFiles) > 20) {
             # close the first/next file in the array
             close(openFiles[++j]".csv")
             openFiles[j]=""
      }
      if (! ($2 in openFiles) ) {
             # put the filename into the openFiles array (just once)
            openFiles[++i]=$2
            }    if (! hdrPrinted[$2]){
   print hdr > (""$2".csv")
  hdrPrinted[$2]=$2   }   print $1, $2, $3> (""$2".csv") 2017-01.csv
```

IHTH

Edit by Ed Morton:

```
awk -F, '
FNR==1 { hdr=$0; next}
{
    out = $2 ".csv"
    if (!seen[out]++) {
        print hdr > out
    }
    print >> out
    close(out)
}
' file
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get syntax error for the '=' in hdrPrinted[$2]=$2.

Comment: Oops, did an inplace update without dbl-checking that it *really* worked ;-( . Here's revised. The date values are indented because field `$1` is included in the output, as you indicated you need to include other fields in your real problem. Good luck.

Comment: So you'll still have to play with what you assign to `hdr` and what fields (and in what order)  you want to output. A `printf("%s\t\%s\n, $1, $2)` sort of statement will give you a lot more flexibility in your output.

Comment: that is basic cmd and should work. Please send output of `uname -svr ; awk --version`.

Comment: Okay, your code worked but only if I save it as a awk file and run it as sh file.awk. At first, I was trying to put all your code in 1 line and running directly on bash and that didn't work. Any idea why? How can I change it into a one-liner that I can copy/paste into bash directly?

Comment: `if (! hdrPrinted[$2]){
      print hdr > (""$2".csv");
      hdrPrinted[$2]=$2
  }` = `if (! hdrPrinted[$2]++ ){
      print hdr > ($2".csv")
  }`. The `""`s in the scripts are doing nothing btw. Also, this will fail after about 20 unique `$2` values unless you're using GNU awk to handle the "too many open files" issue.

Comment: @EdMorton : *The `""`s in the scripts are doing nothing*. Yes, so I thought too, but I couldn't get it to work without them. I am still using the AST awk, so that may explain it. AND I am used to assigning the outputfilename to a variable and then doing `print "stuff" > outputFile`, but didn't want to spend more time figuring that out. YES, Also aware of the 20 file issue. I'll update to take care of that. Thanks for your feedback! Good luck to all.

Comment: I can't make it work without the " " either. I must keep them in the code. Maybe my version. Haven't tried your code on my real file yet because I need to do some other stuff before I attempt it. Your code worked without issues on my small test file perhaps because there were only 2 unique values and didn't hit the 20.

Comment: I've never heard of AST awk but if you're using an awk that needs `""` then **it is broken** and if it's broken in that regard then who knows what other breakage it has so you should stop using it and get a different awk (preferably GNU awk), The simple way to deal with the too many open files issue, btw, is to close the file after every write and then use `>>` on each write instead of `>`. You'd just have to make sure the files were empty or didn't exist before starting to run the script but a clean directory will do that. Or you can add a "seen[]" test before the first write to `>` it.

Comment: I just noticed - you're storing $2 in your openFiles array, but the file name you're writing to is $2".csv", not just $2, so you won't close the files you're opening. Also your test for `$2 in openFiles` will never succeed as the `in` operator tests for $2 being an **index** of openFIles when instead $2 is stored as the value indexed by `++i`.

Comment: Dang. Without an easy way to test code and confirm, I'm happy to have the extra eyes on this. This is why I usually use a form like `openFiles[$2]=$2.  I'll add another array to manage the numbered index. And of course add the ".csv" to the close cmd. But my dog needs a walk now and its late, and will be busy for a while tomorrow. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @EdMorton, I am using awk on Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10. Perhaps that why it is different and/or broken.

Comment: @PythonGuy yeah, I don't know what "Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10" is or what versions of what tools come with it or what it's quoting rules are (hopefully not the usual Windows quoting nightmare!). I always use cygwin to get a shell on top of Windows and everything works great except locales.

Comment: @shelter - I hope you don't mind but I editted your answer to provide a suggestion on a way to avoid the too many open files issue. I'd have left it in a comment but I couldn't take seeing it crushed into 1 line! Feel free to ignore and/or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is tested on a csv containing multiple columns with column two set to date:

```
awk -F',' 'prev!=$2{close(prev".csv");print "date" > ($2".csv")}{print $2 > ($2".csv");prev=$2}' Input_file
```

hth

Comment: Your code works but has the same problem as with Ravinder's answer. I have multiple columns other than "date". So I need my header to be more than just "date". Could you tell me how to print NR==1{header=$0; next} before beginning of each csv?

Comment: Surely it's obvious that if your real input file has more columns than just date then the sample input you provided for us to test a potential solution against should also have more columns than just date.

Comment: It was supposed to be a working example, not a copy/paste from my original dataset. I did mention I have more than 1 column. So no, it wasn't obvious to me. Thank you for your help.